# How to use proxy with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, proxy

I am trying to scrape a site "https://shmoti.com" but it seems they have blocked my ip. So I am trying to use a proxy with node.js .

I am using `node-fetch` module to get the html body of the site .

How to use proxy with `node-fetch`? Also I don't know where to get such free proxies . Any help with this ?

I need to use **fetch** module itself since  I am doing all my processing async way .

Comment: face it, that site does not want you *borrowing* their resources

Comment: Use Request module to request their resources and use cherio js to parse the data

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch#options

it says that from their documentation

```
{
// These properties are part of the Fetch Standard
method: 'GET',
headers: {},        // request headers. format is the identical to that accepted by the Headers constructor (see below)
body: null,         // request body. can be null, a string, a Buffer, a Blob, or a Node.js Readable stream
redirect: 'follow', // set to `manual` to extract redirect headers, `error` to reject redirect

// The following properties are node-fetch extensions
follow: 20,         // maximum redirect count. 0 to not follow redirect
timeout: 0,         // req/res timeout in ms, it resets on redirect. 0 to disable (OS limit applies)
compress: true,     // support gzip/deflate content encoding. false to disable
size: 0,            // maximum response body size in bytes. 0 to disable
agent: null         // http(s).Agent instance, allows custom proxy, certificate, lookup, family etc.
```

}

so probably you could try

```
fetch('example.com',{
        agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://127.0.0.1:8580')
    }).then(function(res){
    ...
})
```